# can I load an external page without redirecting to it?

Tags: php, javascript, load

I want to run HTML Page 1 and when it finish loading, I want to make it load HTML Page 2 but without redirecting to Page 2. Just to run the action that is there but to stay on Page 1. 
I'm not sure if you can do something like that using PHP, JS or META Tags, but there is probably a way.

Please let me know.
Thanks in advance!

Comment: consider or file_get_contents function in PHP or iFrames?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it through javascript, but i'd call it generally bad form.

The example below uses jQuery for brevity.

```
$(window).load(function(){
   $('#dynamic').load('page2.html');
});
```

You must have a container to replace, in this case we're using a div with an ID of 'Dynamic'.

Answer (score 0):

See http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.get/

As you can read, only the first argument is mandatory. That means that if you don't supply it, the page is requested and fetched, but the result is not used for anything. It sounds like that is what you want.